# Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable iff $f$ squared is Riemann integrable for strictly positive

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Prove that the following are equivalent for non-negative function $f$ bounded on $[a,b]$
1. $f$ is riemann integrable
2. $f$ squared is riemann integrable

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Lebesgue criterion?

Comment: yes i can use it

Answer (score 1):

For $f$ nonnegative, the functions $f$ and $f^2$ have the same set of discontinuities. Moreover, a bounded function on a compact interval is Riemann integrable if and only if its set of discontinuities has Lebesgue measure zero.

Hence, $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $f^2$ is Riemann integrable **[for $f$ nonnegative, as in the question]**.

Comment: Note that $f$ being nonnegative is really necessary here. For example, one might define $f(x) = \mathbb 1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=-1$ otherwise, while $f^2(x) = 1$, for all $x$. Thus, sets of discontinuities are not the same for $f$ and $f^2$. The key is that $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous bijection on $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: Sorry if I was misunderstood, this comment wasn't to correct you, just to elaborate on your first sentence. Feel free to add it to your answer if you want, or we can just leave it as comment.

Comment: @Ennar On the contrary, your comment is quite welcome. I just made it clearer in my answer.

Comment: so is it that simple? Do i need to show somehow that they have the same set of discontinuities?

Comment: Do convince yourself (or prove) that $f$ and $f^2$ have the same set of discontinuities.

Comment: @user315479, can you prove that if $g$ is continuous, then "$f$ continuous at $x$ implies $g\circ f$ continuous at $x$"? Can you see how my comment above provides a counterexample to the converse? Can you improve condition on $g$ such that the converse holds? If yes, you have a proof that $f$ and $f^2$ have the same sets of discontinuities for $f\geq 0$.

Comment: so if f,g are both positive and continuous then there is no problem with f∘g (or f squared) but if one of them is not then what?

Comment: @user315479, not quite. You can't force conditions on $f$, only on $g$. Positivity only plays role in your particular example when $g(x) = x^2$. Also, not to disturb Jonas anymore by spamming the comments here, if you can't work it out yourself, I could write it down in another answer.

Comment: okay then how do i show that both f and f squared have the same set of discontinuities

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the fact that if $g$ is continuous on a closed interval containing the range of a Riemann integrable function $f$ on $[a,b],$ then $g\circ f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b].$ For the problem at hand, apply the above with $g(x) = x^2$ or $g(x) = \sqrt x$ to get the desired equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to avoid using Lebesgue criterion...

There is a theorem stating that for $f$ Riemann-integrable and $g$ continuous, $g \circ f$ is Riemann integrable.

From that:

1. If $f$ is Riemann integrable, $f^2 = h \circ f$ is integrable as $h : x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous.
2. If $f^2$ is Riemann integrable then $f = k \circ f$ is Riemann integrable as $k : x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is continuous and $f$ supposed to be non-negative.

Comment: There is an important detail here related to the proof: Riemann integrable functions are always bounded, so their codomain can always be taken to be compact. Thus we can get for free that $g$ is uniformly continuous (on the codomain of $f$) by merely assuming it is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

To provide more details on the answer by Jonas, as requested by OP, I will show why $f$ and $f^2$ have the same sets of discontinuities.

> *Claim 1:* Let $f\colon A\to B$ (not necessarily continuous) and $g\colon B\to C$ continuous function. Then:
>
> $f$ is continuous at $x$ $\implies$ $g\circ f$ is continuous at $x$

This is straightforward from any definition of continuity, since $g$ is continuous at $f(x)$ by our assumption.

The converse doesn't hold in general, for example, one might take bounded $
f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$
$$f(x)=\left\{
{\begin{array}{r l}
1, &x\in\mathbb Q\cap[a,b] \\
-1, &\text{otherwise}
\end{array}}\right.$$ and continuous $g(x) = x^2$, in which case we have that $(g\circ f)(x) = 1$ is continuous, but $f$ isn't.

But, if we furthermore assume that $g$ is bijective, then the converse holds as well:

> *Claim 2:* Let $f\colon A\to B$ (not necessarily continuous) and $g\colon B\to C$ continuous *bijection*. Then:
>
> $f$ is continuous at $x$ $\iff$ $g\circ f$ is continuous at $x$

*Proof.* One direction comes from Claim 1. To get the other direction, apply Claim 1 on $g\circ f$ and $g^{-1}$, i.e. since $g\circ f$ is continuous at $x$, $g^{-1}\circ(g\circ f) = f$ is continuous at $x$ as well. $\square$

How does this prove that $f$ and $f^2$ have the same sets of discontinuities for nonnegative $f$? Well, $g\colon\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$, given by $g(x) = x^2$ is bijective and continuous, so $f^2 = g\circ f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $f$ is continuous at $x$, by our Claim 2.

And this is where we need to stress that $f$ being nonnegative is paramount since $x\mapsto x^2$ is bijective only on nonnegative reals, so $f$ must be nonnegative as well, otherwise we can't apply our Claim 2.

Comment: @user315479, please let me know if this makes everything clear to you. Also, other answers use similar argument, but directly for Riemann integrability.